# How to make comment multi line in TypeScript (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a problem to make comment multi line in typescript angular 2. I just want to comment this code :

```
    protected _checkingList(data, lists:Array<any>){
    let value = false;
    //if (data['__children'].length > 0){
    //    value = this.percobaanCentangMajuMundukCantik(data, data['__children'],data['__children'].length);
    //}
    if (data.value == true){
        value = true;
    }

    return value;
}
```

symbol "//" is the single comment in typescript, i want to make multiline comment, does anyone know how to make it ?

Comment: `/* */` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following is a multiline comment:

```
/* */
```

It uses the same commenting syntax as vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can wrap your code with `/*your code here*/`

```
protected _checkingList(data, lists:Array<any>){
    let value = false;
    /*if (data['__children'].length > 0){
        value = this.percobaanCentangMajuMundukCantik(data, data['__children'],data['__children'].length);
    }*/
    if (data.value == true){
        value = true;
    }

    return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert multi line code into comments in typescript using ^+/ to toggle code in comments

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Eisenberg already answered to add more info incase anyone needs it.

Block Comment

```
/*
 * This is a 
 * Block Comment
 */
```

In Visual Studio Code Editor

select the text and press: Shift + Alt + A
Block Comment: Shift + Alt + A

Comment: This doesn’t add any new information compared to the previous answers. You mention a keyboard shortcut but not which development environment this is for.